# Upload files from django to a specific directory in a server?

Tags: python, django, django-admin

I have a django-admin panel and a Windows Virtual Private Server. 
What i want to do is upload files from django admin panel to a directory like this :

```
C:\site\media
```

and i dont want to upload files to django app folder .

This is my settings.py file :

```
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'static')
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
if not os.path.exists(MEDIA_ROOT):
    os.makedirs(MEDIA_ROOT)
```

and This is my model :

```
class Pictures(models.Model):
    product = models.ForeignKey('Products', models.DO_NOTHING)
    picurl = models.ImageField()
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.title
    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'pictures'
        verbose_name_plural = "ProductPicturess"

    def __str__(self):
        return '%s------- (%s)' % (self.product.title,self.picurl)
```

How should i change it's values ?

Thank you .

Comment: You can use [**`upload_to`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.FileField.upload_to) argument in the model field to specify the target location.

Comment: @JPG exactly how ? when i use upload_to option in my model field , it's always goes in django's app folder

Comment: can you show that model?

Comment: @JPG can you give me an example about this ?

Comment: @JPG , I'll Update the answer

Answer (score 0):

After Searching alot and triying different values finally i found the solutin .

Simply I changed MEDIA_ROOT to this :

```
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, '../../../realwamp/wamp64/www/myproject/pictures/')
```

And volla , My Problem is solved .

With three pairs of dots like ../../../ I back to the C:\ directory and then go to my www folder .